# iphone's phone number splitting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, phone-number

iPhone has a pretty good telephone number splitting function, for example:

Singapore mobile: +65 9852 4135
Singapore resident line: +65 6325 6524
China mobile: +86 135-6952-3685
China resident line: +86 10-65236528
HongKong: +886 956-238-82
USA: +1 (732) 865-3286

Notice the nice features here:
- the splitting of country code, area code, and the rest is automatic;
- the delimiter is also nicely adopted to different countries, e.g. "()", "-" and space.

**Note** the parsing logic is doable to me, however, I don't know where to get the knowledge of most countries' telephone number format.
where could i found such knowledge, or an open source code that implemented it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get similar functionality with the libphonenumber code library.

Comment: aha, so i should thought this: who will provide the save feature as you? the rival, of course! :D

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, you cannot use an `NSNumberFormatter` for this, but you can write your own custom class for it. Just create a new class, set properties such as `countryCode`, `areaCode` and `number`, and then create a method that formats the number based on the `countryCode`.

Here's a great example: http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html

Comment: well, the challenge is not coding, but knowledge of, i don't know, 200 countries in the world?

Comment: Rather than getting annoyed with people who take the time to try to help you, perhaps you could take more time in formulating what part of the problem you're unable to solve. What you want is a table of formats, not way of formatting numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I realize the original question is ambiguous.. i didn't state the problem is parsing, or the telephone code domain knowledge for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: a friend told me about a *gigantic* regular expression he had to maintain that could pick telephone numbers out of intercepted communications from hundreds of countries around the world. It was very non-trivial.

Thankfully your problem is easier, as you can just have a table with the per-country formats:

```
format[usa] = "+d (ddd) ddd-dddd";
format[hk] = "+ddd ddd-ddd-dd";
format[china_mobile] = "+dd ddd-dddd-dddd";
...
```

Then when you're printing, you simply output one digit from the phone number string in each `d` spot as needed. This assumes you know the country, which is a safe enough assumption for telephone devices -- pick "default" formats for the few surrounding countries.

Since [some countries have different formats with different lengths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Germany) you *might* need to store your table with additional information:

```
format[germany][10] = "..."
format[germany][11] = "....."
```